# Mersenne Numbers 1+4k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $M$ be the set of all $a=1+4k$, $k\geq 0$. If $a, ab \in M$ then $b$ is in $M$. It's probably really easy, I just need a hint. Thank you.

Comment: A [Mersenne number](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=MersenneNumber) has the form $2^n - 1$, for $n$ a positive integer (usually prime).  Why did you mention these in your title?  It seems out of place.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**:

$\left(1+4k\right)b=1+4m\iff b=1+4\left(m-kb\right)$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

All integers are of one of this forms:

$$4k \hspace{1cm} 4k+1 \hspace{1cm} 4k+2 \hspace{1cm} 4k+3$$

Multiply those by $4k'+1$ and see wich cases lead to an element of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b∉M$ then $b$ is one of the form $4k, 4k+2, 4k+3.$ This would be help for you.